# Extract all values from Json Array in SQL

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have SQL-data, with one column of JSON-data. Unfortunately, my database only compatibility level 100. So I can't use `OPENJSON()`.

My JSON-data are structured as follows, it contains results from testing. I also have the columns `id`, `model` and `type`.

```
[
{ "name": "rtc", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "battery", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "connection", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "timer", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "provide", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "request", "value": "fail" }
]
```

How do I get columns for `rtc`, `battery`, `connection`, `timer`, `provide` and `request` with cells that are `pass`/`fail`?

Some products have all tests, while some only have a few.

I have tried `JSON_Value(details, '$.name')`, but that gives me null.

*EDIT*
Expected output table, Either of the works:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your expected output table?

Comment: If you are in compatibility 100 are you *at least* on a version that supports JSON (2016+)? If not, T-SQL is completely the wrong language to consume your JSON in.

Comment: Yes, it supports  JSON (2016+)

Comment: If you run the code under the `master` database, you should be able to use `OPENJSON`

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL Server version supports JSON, you may try to parse the stored JSON data and pivot the rows:

Sample data:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
{ "name": "rtc", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "battery", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "connection", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "timer", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "provide", "value": "pass" }, 
{ "name": "request", "value": "fail" }
]'
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES (1, @json)) v (id, details)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT d.id, j.[name], j.[value]
   FROM Data d
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.details) WITH (
      [name] nvarchar(50) '$.name',
      [value] nvarchar(4) '$.value'
   ) j
) t
PIVOT (
   MAX([value]) FOR [name] IN ([rtc], [battery], [connection], [timer], [provide], [request])
) p
```

Result:

| id | rtc | battery | connection | timer | provide | request |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pass | pass | pass | pass | pass | fail |

Note, that you may get the unpivoted values with the following statement:

```
SELECT d.id, j.[name], j.[value]
FROM Data d
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(d.details) WITH (
   [name] nvarchar(50) '$.name',
   [value] nvarchar(4) '$.value'
) j
```

Comment: Personally I would do `FROM Date d CROSS APPLY ( SELECT ... FROM OPENJSON... PIVOT ...)` feels more efficient https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b588c9901a5d41fca9345c2f38033198

Comment: @Charlieface, yes, it's another option.